# Trying to create a circular rotating menu with 8 radials

Tags: flutter, dart, menu, flutter-layout

[image]

I have tried several packages and found the following package fulfilling the purpose to some extent. https://pub.dev/packages/circle_list

One requirement missing in this package is the click-on icon and icon rotating in the center.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. With `RotateMode.stopRotate` everything is working as you wanted it to be, but if you plan to allow the user to rotate it, then the order of elements (indexes) becomes messed up, so in that case, you'll need to figure out how to track the latest position of the first element to know where the start is and where it should go (and I'm not sure if it's even possible with this package).

```
class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  const Sample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<Sample> createState() => _SampleState();
}

class _SampleState extends State<Sample> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController = AnimationController(
      upperBound: pi * 2,
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  List<int> elements = List.generate(10, (index) => index);

  _center(int index) {
    final angle = (pi * 2) * (index / 10);
    animationController.animateTo(angle);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: const Drawer(),
      body: Center(
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: animationController,
          builder: ((context, child) {
            return CircleList(
              onDragEnd: () => {},
              initialAngle: -animationController.value - pi / 2,
              centerWidget: Text('center'),
              rotateMode: RotateMode.stopRotate,
              origin: Offset(0, 0),
              children: elements
                  .map(
                    (index) => IconButton(
                      onPressed: () => _center(index),
                      icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
                      color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(index * 0.05 + .3),
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for doing valuable time for solving my problem but sir I'm trying exactly like this:- https://sendgb.com/ncV2Zv1kYe6

Answer (score 0):

Source Code

```
class RotatingSliderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const RotatingSliderWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RotatingSliderWidget> createState() => _RotatingSliderWidgetState();
}

class _RotatingSliderWidgetState extends State<RotatingSliderWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController = AnimationController(
      upperBound: pi * 2,
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  ContentModel? center;

  final elements = [
    ContentModel(index: 0, backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFFEC38)),
    ContentModel(index: 1, backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFEA1863)),
    ContentModel(index: 2, backgroundColor: Colors.black),
    ContentModel(index: 3, backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFF44133)),
    ContentModel(index: 4, backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF1B97F3)),
    ContentModel(index: 5, backgroundColor: Colors.white),
    ContentModel(index: 6, backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF58BA61)),
    ContentModel(index: 7, backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF9F9F9F)),
  ];

  _center(int index) {
    center = elements[index];
    final angle = (pi * 2) * (index / 10);
    animationController.animateTo(angle);
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: const Drawer(),
      body: Center(
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: animationController,
          builder: ((context, child) {
            return CircleList(
                centerWidget: center == null
                    ? null
                    : Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: center!.backgroundColor,
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        ),
                        child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () => _center(center!.index),
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications, size: 35),
                          color: const Color(0xFFA6F4CE),
                        ),
                      ),
                onDragStart: (_) {},
                onDragEnd: () {},
                outerCircleColor: const Color(0xFFA6F4CE),
                initialAngle: -animationController.value - pi / 2,
                rotateMode: RotateMode.stopRotate,
                origin: const Offset(0, 0),
                children: elements
                    .map((index) => Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: index.backgroundColor,
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          ),
                          child: IconButton(
                            onPressed: () => _center(index.index),
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications, size: 35),
                            color: const Color(0xFFA6F4CE),
                          ),
                        ))
                    .toList());
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ContentModel {
  final int index;
  final Color backgroundColor;

  ContentModel({required this.index, required this.backgroundColor});
}
```

You can see [Result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WJMACXGiQnv4atIVvInz3Kf6_dGO1St6/view?usp=share_link) in attached video

Comment: Thank you sir for doing valuable time for solving my problem but sir I'm trying exactly like this:- https://sendgb.com/ncV2Zv1kYe6

Comment: @ArjunYadav what you are trying to show is not visible can you post screenshot